# How do set the delimiter to " when using AWK in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

So I have a text file with

```
"sam", "james", "john"
"luke", "polly", "jack"
```

I am looking for an awk command that will isolate each name. I seem to be running into the issue that awk does not like me setting " as the delimiter

I would like it to look like

```
sam
luke
```

if I were to try and print field 0

I have tried these commands

```
awk -F""" '{print $0}' test.txt
awk -F"\"" '{print $0}' test.txt
awk -F'"' '{print $0}' test.txt
awk -F'\"' '{print $0}' test.txt
awk -F" '{print $0}' test.txt
```

None of those seems to have worked. This is my first time asking a question on here. Also started learning to code about 5 weeks ago as well :D so I hope this makes sense, isn't a dumb question and that I formatted it all correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following. Basically you need to print the correct field number here to get your expected output. That field number would be 2nd field.

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Wow, that was a fast response. I thought the first field was 0 not 1 thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- extracting all names into a linear list :

> ```
> gawk '!_<NR' RS='[^[:alpha:]]+'
> ```

```
sam
james
john
luke
polly
jack
```

- extracting just 1st column :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='^\"|\",.+$' OFS=
> ```

```
sam
luke
```